# Periodically publish a data dump of all IDs in the image ID space (and make it available in SEDE)

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer, images, data-dump

I see that Imgur has an API to query for image IDs in its ID space, but api.stack.imgur.com is not an API endpoint (and SE is moving off Imgur anyway). Say I want to get all the IDs of images in Stack Exchange's collection of images to do analysis / research. I don't see a better way to get it right now than to brute-force it. This is a request that the data dumps include a dump of "occupied"/used image IDs- including those that are not referenced anywhere in public Q&A or chat.

Answer (score 4):

> This is a request that the data dumps include a dump of "occupied"/used image IDs.

You can download all Stack Exchange images on https://github.com/Franck-Dernoncourt/Stack-Exchange-Image-Dataset

The dataset contains all the ~8.7 million images hosted on i.stack.imgur.com that are linked to in the posts, post histories and comments from the Stack Exchange Data Dump.

Comment: Well there are more (e.g. in chat, or images uploaded but never actually posted) but yeah, that should be the vast majority.

Comment: @ShadowWizardLoveZelda Thanks, yes, I focused on the "most important" images, i.e. all the images needed to preserve the QA content.

Comment: this is not my goal. I want _every_ image ID. I know how to get the ones that are on public Q&A myself using cross-site SEDE.